# Is there a library for C that provides priority queues?

Tags: c, linux, priority-queue

Is there a library for C that provides priority queues?
I'm interested in open source libraries that are commonly installed on Linux machines, something of the kind of glib, which provides some data structures.

Answer (score 5):

Some random link:

- [PQLib](https://bitbucket.org/trijezdci/pqlib/src)
- [libpqueue](https://github.com/vy/libpqueue)
- [pqueue-heap-c](http://code.google.com/p/pqueue-heap-c/)

### Edit:

In general, books dealing with **Linux Kernel** and **Linux System Programming** contain valuable materials related to queues and their implemention details.

Comment: None of those seem to be available in Debian repo, making them less general.

Comment: I suggest you another promising direction to search if you are interested in some queue data structure frequently used in linux: Delve into *book* treating *linux kernel*. You will found plenty of them there. I'm not sure it's a satisfactory answer but you can anyway notify me if you want some reference.

Comment: The problem is that it adds more code to be maintained when it's homemade or updated when it's a third-party library outside of repo. Also I would need to paste the code/non repo library everytime I want to use it in some program. If nothing better, I'll just wrap the STL implementation to use in C.

Comment: I think an edit may improve your question. The more it is focused, the more you get valuable feedback.

Comment: Yes indeed, they are all there! But people have to dig deeper in the comments to fetch more relevant inputs: eg. It seems your work under Debian and want someone to point you to a package available in the repository including the implementation of a priority queue.

Comment: DO NOT USE PQLIB. Not finished and does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to just use message queues, depending on how big the queues need to be.

With posix message queues (see `man mq_overview`) you can set message priorities.

Alternately, with System V message queues (`msgget()`, `msgsnd()`, `msgrcv()`), you can use the message type as a priority and try retrieving each priority (type) in sequence from highest priority to lowest.

In either case they're standard IPC, and should be available on any normal Linux distribution.